# How can I get the hidden Ham marble skin on Super Blocky Ball?

Tags: roblox

I can easily look for a video on all the marble skins. My only problem is that the Ham marble (found on the Roblox Circuit stage atop the waterfall) is seemingly impossible to get. Can anyone help me on how to get the Ham marble? I don't have a reliable source for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I looked it up and it seems that the only way to get the marble is to jump up to the waterfall. It is possible, however.

> 3:04